# URL format for boto storage on django with SSL

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to get Boto to format my urls as: `//s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/FILEPATH/` but it is always returning `//BUCKETNAME/s3.amazonaws.com/FILEPATH` instead.  I found something about the CallingFormat (http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/ref/s3.html) but am not sure what to do with it.

I then have:

`STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'`

http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html says you can set a setting `AWS_CALLING_FORMAT` to specify what I want but I don't seem to be getting it.

The URLs are generated in the templates with the usual:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% static 'FILEPATH' %}
```

Comment: What code is currently generating the urls whose formatting is incorrect?

Comment: @AdamKG updated with more info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not tested, but [based on the source](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/src/e27c8b61ab57e5afaf21cccfee005c980d89480f/storages/backends/s3boto.py?at=default#cl-231), I think what you want is:

```
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat()
```

(OC you'll need to have `import boto.s3.connection` somewhere above)

Note the setting name - it doesn't match what's in the django-storages docs.

The django-storages docs seem to be more oriented towards the plain s3 backend, which is a shame, the boto one is much nicer.

If it's not working, also make sure you're on `1.1.8` - not sure which version started supporting this, but the s3boto backend underwent [some big changes](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/diff/storages/backends/s3boto.py?diff1=12fd16b0fa85&diff2=02afdf3d27871a3588ede24b00e4fdb9e99cd807&at=default) at the beginning of the year, this wouldn't work on a 2012 release of django-storages.

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar.  You have no idea how much time you just saved me.  Cheers! 